# same coupon code should apply for diferent conditions

Tags: coupon-codes

i want to create a only one coupon code and it should work something like

if subtotal is less than 500 , than 50 discount and if subtotal is more than 500  than 100 discount.

@Amasty posted here [Multiple actions on shopping cart price rule](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16111/multiple-actions-on-shopping-cart-price-rule) : to create 2 different coupons with same coupon codes

but i want to create some 100 coupon codes and those coupon codes should according to above rule

this extension supports what i need, but only for 1 coupon code for one time : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/tiered-coupons.html

please help me to find solution.....

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import same list of coupon codes into each rule.

Do not forget to remove unique index from the table `salesrule_coupon` per another question in your post.

Then each coupon code will trigger both rules, and one will match.