# Using the same Coupon code for multiple Price Rules

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes, price-rules

Does anyone know if it's possible to use the same Coupon Code for multiple price rules. I want to give 10% off Category A and 7% off Category B, if they have any of the qualifying products in their cart.

Currently Magento throws the "Coupon with the same code already exists." but i read that you can disable this by removing the index and updating a core file, but i'm not sure what changes need to be made to the core file.

I'm referring to this comment:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/29360/15768

Grateful for any advice here. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mage_SalesRule_Model_Resource_Coupon

```
    protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('salesrule/coupon', 'coupon_id');
    $this->addUniqueField(array(
        'field' => 'code',
        'title' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Coupon with the same code')
    ));
}
```

Remove the addUniqueField call. Don't modify the core file, override it in a custom module.

You'll also need to modify the table salesrule_coupon

```
`ALTER TABLE salesrule_coupon DROP INDEX UNQ_SALESRULE_COUPON_CODE;`
```

Again, do this in a custom module as opposed to a direct sql call.

Comment: That was not work, I dont found any key like INDEX UNQ_SALESRULE_COUPON_CODE

Comment: @Rajan - This would totally depend on what Magento version you're using. I don't even remember what version this was in reference to, sorry.

Comment: @BenTruby this code is working fine but i am heaving an issue, if i add 1 product in cart its fine but if i add 2 different category products in cart and they have their own discount price and if apply coupon it is showing discount 2 times of current discount, like both products have 100-100 rs discount so total should be 200 but its showing 400 discount.