# Shopping cart price rule : product price percent discount

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I want to create rule to apply 25% of product price but maximum discount amount is 1000 .

So how can I do this?

Comment: @Rakesh. No you don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No coding involved. You can do this from the backend only.
You can create 2 different rules.

- Rule 1: Give a 1000 fixed discount for products where the price is over 4000 (you can also have additional rules if you don't want the discount for all products)
- Rule 2. Give 25% discount for products with price 4000 or below (again, add the same rules as above if you don't want it for all products.)

This way you will never have both rules applied to the same product and if the product price is below 4000 the discount will be below 1000 (25% put of 4000). And if the price is over 4000 the discount will be fixed to 1000.

Comment: but i want this with coupon code so this is not possible for coupon code

Comment: @SnehaPanchal Right. I didn't know that. But you can solve that easily with this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/80547/146. This will allow you to have 1 coupon code for 2 rules or more.

Comment: @SnehaPanchal Create 2 shopping cart rules with the same coupon code. Just remove the unique key index from the database and the rule model

Comment: Please tell me which table