# Magento 2 : Cart Price Rule

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, coupon

How I can create a cart price rule which will provide 10% discount, but max amount of discount should be 100.
For example below are some conditions rule should satisfy:

1. If my cart item total is 500 I should get 50 Off.
2. If my cart item total is 1000 I should get 100 Off.
3. If my cart item total is 2000 still I should get 100 Off.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use 2 cart price rule which can solve your problem, here i am sharing the screenshots of the conditions you should apply.
[image]

above one is the first rule in which i applied 10% discount on the cart amount of 1000 or less than thousand.

[image]

above one is the 2nd cart price rule that if the cart amount is more than thousand i gave fixed amount discount for whole cart that is 100.

Hope this will help you, have a great day :)

Comment: Can I use same coupon for these two different rules?

Comment: You can refer to this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16111/multiple-actions-on-shopping-cart-price-rule  -> Create shopping cart rules with the same coupon code and  remove the unique key index from the database and the rule model.